# Generating new random phases for DFT of 2d uniform distributed noise image changes image distribution

Tags: image-processing, dft, signal-synthesis

My goal is to produce a new random noise image from two already existing noise images. For that I take the absolute values of one image and the angles (phases) from another image in Fourier Space and combine them to create a new image. I notice, that the back-transformed new image shows a more Gaussian shaped distribution of pixel values in its histogram, compared to the input noise images, which are uniformly distributed (see histograms below).

I am generating two random noise images (I_one and I_two) with uniformly distributed pixel values from the interval [0.0, 1.0). I am computing the Discrete Fourier Transfrom of the two images (FT_I_one and FT_I_two) and extract the angles and absolute values of both.

I create a new Image in Fourier Space by combining the absolute values of I_one and the angles of I_two through:
$ FT_{mix} = I_{one,abs} \cdot exp(i \cdot I_{two,angle})$

I backtransform the mix image and plot the absolute values of it.

Then I notice that the change in distribution of pixel values of the original compared to the newly generated image.

Why is that?

How can I generate a new Image in Fourier Space by combining the absolute values of an original image with new angles (phase values), such that the back-transformed image and the original image show the same (equal) distribution of pixel values?

```py
# random noise images, uniformly distributed pixel values from the interval [0.0, 1.0)
I_one = np.random.random(size)
I_two = np.random.random(size)

# DFT
FT_I_one = np.fft.fftn(I_one)
FT_I_one_abs = np.abs(FT_I_one)
FT_I_one_angle = np.angle(FT_I_one)

FT_I_two = np.fft.fftn(I_two)
FT_I_two_abs = np.abs(FT_I_two)
FT_I_two_angle = np.angle(FT_I_two)

# generating the new image with abs values from img_one and phases from img_two
FT_mix = FT_I_one_abs * np.exp(1j * FT_I_two_angle)

# backtransformation
I_mix = np.abs(np.fft.ifftn(FT_mix))
```

[image: np.imshow() plot of I_one]

[image: np.imshow() plot of I_two]

[image: np.imshow() plot of I_mix]

[image: histogram of I_one]

[image: histogram of I_mix]

Comment: Much better! Thank-you!

Comment: It's "a more Gaussian shaped distribution" because of the `abs` at the end. If you take the real component of the IFFT instead you'll see a true Gaussian distribution!

Comment: I don't really have an explanation for this. It's hard to look at the FFTs and see any difference between normal and uniformly distributed noise. Both produce a Gaussian distribution of values in the Fourier domain. I assume there's some specific correlation of values in the uniform case that causes the non-normal distribution in the spatial domain. By combining the phase of one and the magnitude of the other you destroy that. The same happens if you combine the real part of `FT_I_one` with the imaginary part of `FT_I_two`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to think about my question. 
I also thought about it some more and found a possible explanation.
The Central Limit theorem states that the sum of a large number of independent and identically distributed random variables tends to follow a Gaussian distribution regardless of the distribution of individual random variables. 
With the new random phases for the Fourier representation I essentially introduce a large number of random variables, which then leads to the back transformed image to be of gaussian shape.

Comment: I found this blogpost to be helpful:
https://blog.demofox.org/2021/12/29/why-cant-you-design-noise-in-frequency-space/

Comment: Sure, central limit theory is why uniform noise has a normal distribution in the frequency domain. But that doesn’t mean you can’t make uniform noise with the IFFT: `ifft(FT_I_one)` is uniformly distributed after all. But the FT of uniform noise has a specific property, and this property is lost when you mix and match two such FTs. This is quite interesting! I have no idea what this property might be, I can’t discern it by eye from looking at the images. Maybe someone here can show this property mathematically.